# Adding pointer to NSPointerArray causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c

```
static void * pointer = &pointer;

NSPointerArray *array = [NSPointerArray strongObjectsPointerArray];

[array addPointer:pointer];
```

This results in a bad access error on the last line - what am I doing wrong?

#### Update

Changing the initializer to:

```
[[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory];
```

solved the issue, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your `pointer` is not an Objective-C object and cannot be retained.

Comment: @HotLicks why not? Aren't all pointers just pointers?

Comment: Not all things pointed to are alike.  A "strong" pointer is "retained" by the compiler, which means the object is referenced and a reference count in it is incremented.  Your pointer does not lead to anything that looks like an object.  (A "strongObjectsPointerArray" is essentially the same as an NSMutableArray.)

Comment: @HotLicks what about regarding my update - it works, but is it shoddy?

Comment: Well, it goes beyond "shoddy" to do `pointer = &pointer` in any real code, but I assume that that's just for example's sake.